# PHP / TCPDF library - Size an image in a PDF to a specific number of inches?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Does anyone know how to get TCPDF to output a .GIF file with a specific number of inches width x height?

I am trying to get a GIF embedded in a PDF so that it will print at exactly 4x6 inches. I tried this:

```
$this->setpageUnit('in');
$this->Image($tmp, 0, 0, 4, 6, 'gif', '', '', true);
```

But that only seemed to result in a blank page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's happen because you are not using a capital "P"

```
$this->setpageUnit('in');
```

maybe is should be :

```
$this->setPageUnit('in');
```

Comment: Yep, good catch, this should be marked as the correct answer. http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aad2c0cbfe5b6330eed5850f87c2a32d9

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to figure out how many pixel's per inch and then use the method `setImageScale(float $scale);`

For example:

```
$this->setImageScale(24.5);
```

Then your code should work, after setting the scale:

```
$this->Image($tmp, 0, 0, 4, 6, 'gif', '', '', true);
```